# Coldfusion Select Option Value Get Items From Database

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, cfloop

```
        <form action="blog.Logboek" method="post" name="Update_what">
           <select size="1" name="Whats">
               <option>Select an item</option>
                <cfloop array="#VARIABLES.Whats#" item="What_name">
               <option VALUE="#What.id#">#item.What_name#</option>
                </cfloop>
           </select>
           <input type="submit" value="Update_what">
       </form>
```

I get a list of items with what is between the option tag and not the items from the database.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might be overengineering your approach.  If the array is generated from your query results, why not dispense with it and loop through the query instead?

Comment: Exactly. Usage `cfloop` is totally fine with queries. Then you use name of query to get data from each row eg. `getQuery.id` to get every id from query getQuery in cfloop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see your array is named `Whats`. Why are you trying to get the value from a variable named `What`? Also you are improperly calling `item.What_name`.

You should loop through `Whats` like you do and use the `index` attribute eg. `row`.

```
<cfloop array="#VARIABLES.Whats#" index="row">
    <option VALUE="#row.id#">#row.<thing_you_want_to_display>#</option>
</cfloop>
```

This will work if this will be in `cfoutput` tag.

**Update from comments:**

As [noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919756/coldfusion-select-option-value-get-items-from-database#comment57597233_34920147), only Lucee supports the [`item` attribute with array loops](http://docs.lucee.org/reference/tags/loop.html). For Adobe ColdFusion, [use the `index` attribute](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cfloop-looping-over-a-list-a-file-or-an-array.html) instead.

Comment: To clarify, when you [loop through an array](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cfloop.html), the `item` variable gets populated with the array elements, ie `item="What_name"`. So the original code should be using the `What_name` variable to access the element properties, ie `What_name.id`, etcetera. That said, as Dan mentioned above, an may be an over complication ..

Comment: Remember: `cfloop array` with `item` instead of `index` only works with Lucee! It's not compatible with ACF.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for misleading you. I meant to use this `item` when you loop through `query` without putting its content to array. Thanks again.

Comment: @PatNowak - Feel free to rollback the changes, or update your answer to better reflect your original intent. (Thinking it was a typo or something, I just wanted to add a note to avoid confusion for the next guy :)